# How to get the closest element id attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find the closest element that has id attribute and get the `id`. The element could be `<p>, <div>` or other elements.

I have tried

```
element=$('#test').closest('div[id]').attr('id');
```

but it only get the id if the element is a `div`. I want to be more universal. Are there anyways to do this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get rid of the `div` entirely and look for all elements that have an `id` attribute:

```
$('#test').closest('[id]').attr('id');
```

Comment: I *think* you could even forgo the * selector and just use `.closest('[id]')` - I might be wrong though.